# Can I use activerecord mId to select item

Tags: android, activeandroid

I want to send an activeandroid object in intent, but I find it is not serializable. I think I can send mId (what getId() returns) in intent and select record in the new activity. However, how can I select item using mId?

P.S this database does not have primary key for now

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer by looking into source code of Model. Database object can by fetched by function load();